# C++ String to double atof conversion losing precision?

Tags: c++

C++ is not my language so forgive this simple problem. I'm losing precision in an atof conversion from string to double, can anyone help?

```
string lAmount;

string lSuspendedInt = "131663.51";
string lAccruedInterest = "0.0";
double dSuspendedInt= atof(lSuspendedInt.c_str());   //PROBLEM HERE?
double dAccruedInterest = atof(lAccruedInterest.c_str());
double dTotal = dSuspendedInt + dAccruedInterest;

char cAmount[50];

memset(cAmount,0X00,sizeof(cAmount));
  sprintf(cAmount,"%g*",dTotal);
  lAmount = cAmount;


cout << "lAmount: "<<lAmount<<endl; //PRINTING: 131664 not 131663.51
```

I've played with %f in the memset function however this gives 131663.510000

Thanks in advance.

Sapatos

Comment: If I were needing this exact of an amount, I'd consider using fixed point instead.  On the C++ side, I'm sure there are better ways to convert string to double besides atof.  sprintf() is another C way of doing it as well if you think the problem is there.  As a comment as I don't have an exact answer here for you.

Comment: @Michael: one can use streams, though it's bulky, C++0x introduces specific `stof` (and the whole family) instructions as part of the Standard Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `%g` format operator, which isn't specified with enough precision. You might want `%.2f` instead, which prints two digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

The `sprintf` `%g` format specifier defaults to printing six significant digits. If you want more, you can explicitly specify how many should be printed:

```
sprintf(cAmount,"%.8g*",dTotal);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `atof` creates a double.  See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/).  Your problem is that the `%g` returns either the shorter of float or scientific notation.  See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/).  Also note, that you're adding the in `*` notation which signifies that there is an expected truncation in the number of printed characters.

Comment: The `*` notation would need to be before the conversion specifier to have any affect anyway... as is it's just printed out as a normal character.